# Existing Fragment is disappearing after preventing duplicate fragments from being committed

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

So I want to make sure that I don't commit the same Fragment multiple times, to do this I make sure that I only commit a fragment when its the first time. I have implemented it in the following manner. But the problem is even though it doesn't make the commit the second time, it erases my current fragment view(so the view disappears but the fragment is still on the stack)

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val vm = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchPlayerViewModel::class.java)
    setContentView(R.layout.tracked_players_fragment_container)
    val frag = TrackedPlayersFragment.newInstance()
    if(item.itemId == R.id.players_list_button){
        if (!frag.isAdded){
            if (!vm.isTrackedPlayersInitialized()) {
                vm.getTrackedPlayersList()
            }
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(
                    R.id.fragment_container_view_tag,
                    frag, "FRAG_TAG"
                ).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()

            }
        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

To give some context, the new fragment is created when the user presses the action bar button, that is why I have implemented this in onOptionsItemSelected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was the setContentView outside the if statement that was causing the issue.

Comment: That fragment will always be `!isAdded()`. If you want to check if it's already added, use `findFragmentByTag` first.